# pointer being freed was not allocated error?

Tags: c++, list

I have seen many posts for this error. But I'm not reserving memory dynamically or doing anything in destructor:
This program is SSJF algorithm for selecting cylinder in operating system.

I have a simple class called IO:

```
class IO
{
    public:
            IO();
            IO(int,int);
            void setIO(int,int);
            ~IO();
            int trackNo;
            int arrival;
            int start;
            int end;
            bool finished;
};
```

Here is the implementation of the class::

```
IO::IO(int arr, int tNum)
{
    this->arrival = arr;
    this->trackNo = tNum;
    this->start = 0;
    this->end = 0;
}    
IO::IO()
{

}

IO::~IO()
{

}    
void IO::setIO(int t1, int t2)
{
    this->trackNo = t1;
    this->arrival = t2;
}
```

And finally here is part of main program:

```
list<IO> myList;
....
myList.push_back(tmpIO); //Add to the list
...
list<IO> wt_list;
```

And later I'm trying to do some operations. I have deleted some of the part which is not related.

```
    //list<IO>::iterator itMin;
    while(myList.size()>0)
    {
        //If it is the first input just get it
        if(f)
        {

            IO selected = myList.front();
            curr_time += selected.arrival + selected.trackNo;
            f=false;
            cout << selected.arrival<<endl;
            lastPos = selected.trackNo;
            myList.pop_front();

        }
        //Check if there is any item to add to queue
        while(myList.front().arrival <  curr_time)
        {
            wt_list.push_back(myList.front());
             myList.pop_front(); //Error is coming from this line
        }

        while(wt_list.size()>0)
        {

        }
```

Error message:

malloc: *** error for object 0x10f68b3e0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Anyone can help me and explain why I get this error and how can I skip it?

Comment: so, where do you get the error? have you tried running your program in a debugger?

Comment: Please post the exact error message, and (if possible), add comments to your code sample to show which line(s) the error refers to.

Comment: I have added more information. Error is coming from third part where I have commented.

Comment: How many items are in `myList` when the error is thrown?

Comment: @Johnsyweb There is 3 items in the list

Comment: I'm trying to push from one list to another list and deleted from the source list...

Comment: To put it another way, just before the error is thrown, you call `mylist.pop_front()`: what is `mylist.size()` ***at that point***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest code I can come up with to reproduce this error looks like this:

```
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> mylist;
    mylist.pop_front();
}
```

I can prevent the error by doing:

```
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> mylist;
    if (!mylist.empty())
    {
        mylist.pop_front();
    }
}
```

You're calling:

```
myList.pop_front();
```

...within a `while`-loop, which in turn is within a `while`-loop that also calls `myList.pop_front()`.

I can only suggest that you debug your code to see how many times `pop_front()` is invoked for  `mylist`. My money is on it being more than `mylist.size()` times, [hence my question in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19546982/78845#comment29003927_19546982) (with new emphasis):

> How many items are in `myList` ***when the error is thrown***?

Perhaps the simplest fix will be to replace...

```
    //Check if there is any item to add to queue
    while(myList.front().arrival <  curr_time)
    {
        wt_list.push_back(myList.front());
         myList.pop_front(); //Error is coming from this line
    }

    while(wt_list.size()>0)
    {

    }
```

...with...

```
    while (!mylist.empty() && myList.front().arrival < curr_time)
    {
        wt_list.push_back(myList.front());
        myList.pop_front();
    }

    while (!wt_list.empty())
    {
    }
```

...but it's hard to tell from the snippet you've provided.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. You were right. The list was empty after couple of iterations...

Comment: I thought that would probably be the case. Good luck!